# Weakening of a topological functor

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology

In the definition of a [topological functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category) we require that every (possibly large) structured sink has a unique initial lift. The sink may be indexed by a class.

**Question.** What is the name of a *faithful* functor which satisfies this definition for small sinks only? What can be said about their relevance? Where have they been studied?

The context of the question is the category $\mathsf{Top}(\mathcal{C})$ of topological space objects internal to a complete category $\mathcal{C}$ studied in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.11115), Section 7. Namely, it can be shown that the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Top}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}$ has lifts of *small* structured sinks. When $\mathcal{C}$ is monocomplete, all structured sinks can be lifted.

Comment: Our of curiosity, could you provide some context for the question?

Comment: @IttayWeiss I have provided some proper context in the question now.